# slow request order by limit

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1

please help to reduce the time of response of this request (2.8 sec):

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE trk.TrkTypeID ,  trk.TrkID , st.Alias

FROM tracking trk 
INNER JOIN TrackingEnv trkenv ON trk.TrkID = trkenv.TrkID 
INNER JOIN Job jb  on jb.JobID=trk.JobID 
INNER JOIN statustype st on st.StatusTypeID = jb.StatusTypeID 

WHERE trk.TrkTypeID IN ( 2,3,10) AND trkenv.EnvID IN ( 1,1,20 ) 
Order BY jb.StartDate DESC LIMIT 0 , 10
```

and the explain on this request give :

```
select-type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra

SIMPLE | st | index | PRIMARY | Alias | 62 | null | 6 | Using index;Using temporary;Using filesort
SIMPLE | jb | ref | PRIMARY,StatusTypeID | StatusTypeID  | 3 | base.st.StatusTypeID  | 4739 | 
SIMPLE | trk | ref | PRIMARY,JobID,TrkTypeID | JobID  | 4 | base.jb.JobID | 1 | Using where;
SIMPLE | trkenv | ref | TrkID_EnvID | TrkID_EnvID | 4 | base.trk.TrkID | 1 | Using where;Using index
```

these are de tablese's definition :

Job Table :

```
CREATE TABLE `job` (
`JobID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`StartDate` datetime NOT NULL,
`EndDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`Duration` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`ParentJobID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`SessionJobID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`JobTypeID` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
`StatusTypeID` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
`Visible` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`EnvID` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
`Description` text,
PRIMARY KEY (`JobID`),
KEY `ParentJobID` (`ParentJobID`),
KEY `SessionJobID` (`SessionJobID`),
KEY `JobTypeID` (`JobTypeID`),
KEY `StatusTypeID` (`StatusTypeID`),
KEY `EnvID` (`EnvID`),
KEY `StartDate` (`StartDate`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_job_environment` FOREIGN KEY (`EnvID`) REFERENCES `environment`   (`EnvID`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_job_job` FOREIGN KEY (`ParentJobID`) REFERENCES `job` (`JobID`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_job_jobtype` FOREIGN KEY (`JobTypeID`) REFERENCES `jobtype` (`JobTypeID`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_job_job_2` FOREIGN KEY (`SessionJobID`) REFERENCES `job` (`JobID`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_job_statustype` FOREIGN KEY (`StatusTypeID`) REFERENCES `statustype` (`StatusTypeID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Tracking  Table :

```
CREATE TABLE `tracking` (
`TrkID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`TrkTypeID` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
`JobID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`Visible` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`EnvID` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
`TrkStatusTypeID` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`LockUserID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`TrkID`),
KEY `JobID` (`JobID`),
KEY `LockUserID` (`LockUserID`),
KEY `TrkStatusTypeID` (`TrkStatusTypeID`),
KEY `EnvID` (`EnvID`),
KEY `TrkTypeID` (`TrkTypeID`),
CONSTRAINT `tracking_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`TrkTypeID`) REFERENCES `trackingtype` (`TrkTypeID`),
CONSTRAINT `tracking_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`JobID`) REFERENCES `job` (`JobID`),
CONSTRAINT `tracking_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`EnvID`) REFERENCES `environment` (`EnvID`),
CONSTRAINT `tracking_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`TrkStatusTypeID`) REFERENCES   `trackingstatustype` (`TrkStatusTypeID`),
CONSTRAINT `tracking_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`LockUserID`) REFERENCES `user` (`UserID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=309411 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

TrackingEnv Table :

```
CREATE TABLE `trackingenv` (
`TrkID` int(10) NOT NULL,
`EnvID` int(10) NOT NULL,
`Write` int(10) NOT NULL,
`Read` int(10) NOT NULL,
KEY `TrkID_EnvID` (`TrkID`,`EnvID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

StatusType Table :

```
CREATE TABLE `statustype` (
`StatusTypeID` mediumint(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`LabelID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`Alias` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`StatusTypeID`),
UNIQUE KEY `Alias` (`Alias`),
KEY `LabelID` (`LabelID`),
CONSTRAINT `statustype_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`LabelID`) REFERENCES `label` (`LabelID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Thnaks for your help

Comment: Do you have an index on jb.StartDate?

Comment: Yes i have.and i can force to use index (StartDate) and then it's ok only 0.001 milisecondes but only when i have trk.TrkTypeID in (10 ...) . the nombre of lines who have trk.TrkTypeID = 10  is 300000 ,and 2 ,3 just 1000 lines so forcing index (StartDate) work very quick when i have trk.TrkTypeID in (2,3,10 ..) else if i have trk.TrkTypeID in (2,3) the response increase to 2secondes

Comment: Can you add your DDL information for your tables?

Comment: I have edited my post to write the tables's Definition.